# Understanding how to use functors in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I have this database in Prolog. `I'm trying to write a query that will return the names of all the people who own a honda`.

I know how to do this with just car or truck with owns(X,car(honda,*,*)). , but I'm unsure how to return all the owners from car, truck and motorcycle at the same time.

Any help will be greatly appreciated I've been stuck on this problem for a while.

```
owns(bill, car(ford, mustang, 1964)).
owns(sue, car(pontiac, gto, 1967)).
owns(george, car(honda, civic, 2013)).
owns(betty, truck(ford, f150, 2013)).
owns(henry, motorcycle(honda, goldwing, 2010)).
```

Comment: Consider using more descriptive names for your predicates, like `person_car/2`, to make clear what each argument means.

Answer (score 2):

you could use [univ](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=%28%3D..%29/2)/2

```
?- owns(Person, Owned), Owned =.. [_, honda|_].
```

or [arg](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=arg/3)/3

```
?- owns(Person, Owned), arg(1, Owned, honda).
```

Comment: Thank you! I read something about those two, but didn't really understand how they worked.